# Failing bluetooth sequence

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to make a simple connection sequence to a serial bluetooth device at the beginning of my app. Right now, all of this is inside `onCreate ()`:

```
    BT = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    BT.enable();
    if(!BT.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enabler = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enabler, REQUEST_ENABLE);
        BT.enable();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth On.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //finish apk
        finish();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth On.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    pairedDevices = BT.getBondedDevices();
    pDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

    if (pairedDevices.size()>0) {
        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
        {
            pDevices.add(bt); //Get the device's name and the address
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing paired.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        BluetoothDevice dispositivo = BT.getRemoteDevice(pDevices.get(0).getAddress());
        btSocket = dispositivo.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
        btSocket.connect();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

The goal is to connect to the first available paired device. So far it always displays "Failed." even when I have an unconnected paired device sitting next to the phone.

Should I be doing this somewhere else in the app? I'm not really concerned with delaying the main activity since this is for a personal project.

Edit: spelling

Answer (score 0):

All BT 2.1 devices and newer ones require the secure connection, so use the *createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord* instead of the *createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord*.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out... It was trying to connect to only the first paired connection. I put the try catch on a for loop, now it connects fine :)